# How can I get a list of all columns in the database, along with it's referenced table/column and if it is a primary key with no duplicates? (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Using `information_schema`, I want the table to look similar to this:

```
IS_PRIMARY|TABLE_NAME|COLUMN_NAME|REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME|REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          |           |          |                     |
```

I have a lot of primary keys that are also foreign keys (used for parent-child tables and many-many tables). And I have a lot of foreign keys that are not primary keys and vise versa. I am trying to get a list of all columns, their key-situation, and have no duplicates.

I've been playing around with queries but can't get what I want For example I tried:

```
SELECT COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME,COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_KEY,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
inner join information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
on COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME=KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME AND COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME=KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_SCHEMA='myDatabase'
```

But this has duplicates as well as some missing values. The difficulty with trying to get a table that looks like this is that keys that are both a primary key and a foreign key have two rows in the database, but I don't want the duplicate.

Please help!

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "duplicate"? Do you mean if it's a primary key, don't also return it as a foreign key? Or if you literally mean rows returned are exact duplicates, why does `DISTINCT` not work?

Comment: I mean if a column is both a primary key and a foreign key, I want it to return as one row with "true" (or something similar) in the `IS_PRIMARY` column and the `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` and `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` to return values. Right now, if a column is both a primary key and a foreign key, then it returns two different rows for the same column, one with the primary key and one with the foreign key.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you want. What if a key column if referenced by multiple tables? What about a column that is referenced that isn't a key column? How (realistically) can a column be both a "key column" and a "foreign key column"? I suggest you create a simple example schema in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), post the link into your question along with the desired output, and post a message here so I know you've updated the Q with that info